# style problem with data returned from action method

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Controller action:

```
public string Index(){
var tmp = (from i in Message.message
                  where i.To == "bognjen" && i.Read == false
                  select i.Read).Count().ToString();
        return tmp;
}
```

Part of View:

```
<li><a>Inbox <%=Html.Action("Index","MyController")%></a></li>
```

When action `Index` return string it is not formatted with applyed style for `<li>`. How to format this string?

For example:
 action Index return number 4, then View page show: Inbox 4. Problem: Inbox have one style(font and size) and 4 have other style(with other font and size)

Style for `<li>` is:

```
li {
   list-style:none;
   background:url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat 0 5px;
   padding:3px 0 3px 17px;
}
```

This style should be for returned data from Index action (in my example that is 4)

Comment: Didn't understand your question... What do you want it to be like? Write an example in your question...

Comment: What style should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to do this. For example:

Create this action method on some controller (let's call it `MasterController`):

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult InboxStatus()
{
    var model = new InboxStatusViewModel();
    model.UnreadMessageCount = from i in Message.message
                   where i.To == "bognjen" && i.Read == false
                   select i.Read).Count();

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

`InboxStatusViewModel` is just a POCO.

Then create a partial view `InboxStatus.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<InboxStatusViewModel>" %>

<li><a>Inbox (<%:Model.UnreadMessageCount %>)</a></li>
```

Then just call `Html.RenderAction()` in the view and specify you want `InboxStatus` action from `MasterController`. This will render the link and it will be styled and everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tmp = (from i in Message.message 
                  where i.To == "bognjen" && i.Read == false 
                  select i.Read).Count().ToString();
```

That should return a number.  To format it, add a format string to the `ToString()`

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)